# Cycle count measurement

Tags: profiling

I have a **MS Visual Studio 2005** application solution. All the code is in **C**. I want to measure the number of cycles taken for execution by particular functions. Is there any **Win32 API** which I can use to get the cycle count?

I have used `gettimeofday()` to get time in micro seconds, but I want to know the cycles consumed.

Answer (score 2):

Both Intel and AMD offer windows libraries and tools to access the performance counters on their cpus. These give access not only to cycle counts, but also to cache line hits and misses and TLB flush counts. The Intel tools are marketed under the name VTune, while AMD calls theirs CodeAnalyst.